# Div tag (animation arrow) is not staying at the bottom left hand corner of the page, just above my footer

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I want my bouncing arrow to stay at the left bottom corner of the page (just above my footer) at all times when the browser is resized. However when I resize the browser, the arrow goes all over the place and does not stay fixed at the bottom left corner of the page.

```css
#arrow {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 60;
  bottom: 60;
  left: -7;
  right: -47 width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  -webkit-animation: bounce 2s infinite ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  0%,
  20%,
  60%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="arrow">click me <br>&#11015;</div>
```

Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/dave1231/9xLbpm4d/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like this?
From what I understood you need something stuck at the bottom

```css
#arrow {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    bottom: 4px;
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    -webkit-animation: bounce 2s infinite ease-in-out;
}

#pointer{
text-align:center;

}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  0%, 20%, 60%, 100%  { -webkit-transform: translateY(0); }
    40%  { -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px); }
  80% { -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px); }
}
```

```html
<div id="arrow">click me
<div id="pointer">
&#11015;
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thats looking better, but with your above code its going under my footer now. i tried to play about with the bottom: 4px; and change the number but no luck. What if i want to move it like 3cm up

Comment: Sure, give me a moment and i will send you a js fiddle link

Comment: hey, FYI i figure it out haha it was a silly mistake that i was doing! could you help me with one more thing? you see the arrow is not in the middle of click me its on the left hand side under the word click. is there a way to bring the arrow between click me but under it?